# can't connect to pgbouncer administration database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pgbouncer

I installed pgbouncer and I setup the pgbouncer.ini and my application can connect to pgbouncer and make queries.

But when I try to connect to the virtual administration database of pgbouncer by using the following command

```
psql -p 6543 -U postgres pgbouncer
```

I get the following message

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.6543"?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with host in your connection string. For example, if you used `listen_addr = 127.0.0.1` in your `config` file, then use:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6543 -U postgres pgbouncer
```